# GAE background request error

Tags: google-app-engine, go

i use golang(1.8) on GAE.

i tried [background request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime#background_requests) and it failed.

error message is loot like this.

`API error 2 (system: BACKEND_REQUIRED)`

dev_appserver.py execute command is look like this.
`dev_appserver.py cmd/app.yaml --default_gcs_bucket_name bucketname --enable_watching_go_path=true`

what should i do?

Comment: Can you show your app.yaml file? Are you using manual or basic scaling as shown in the doc you linked?

Comment: runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#scaling_elements) for the app.yaml file, automatic scaling is assumed by default unless you specify otherwise. As per the doc you linked, background requests can run on manual or basic scaling instances only. You'll need to set it in your app.yaml file. For basic scaling for example:

```
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
  idle_timeout: 5m
```

Comment: thanks. It works perfectly well. you are save my time!!